# Change persistence strategy of Ehcache in play application

Tags: java, caching, playframework, ehcache, playframework-2.2

**My Goal**: I want to configure [ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org) to use the **hard drive** for caching. Ideally cache content will survive application restarts.

**Context**: `play 2.2` application with `play-cache_2.10-2.2.2.jar` and `ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar` on classpath

**Try**: I haven't tried too much yet, because the first attempt indicates that I'm missing something fundamentally.

I just created a `ehcache.xml` file under `app/conf`

```
<ehcache>
    <diskStore path="/var/myapp/persistent/cache>
    <defaultCache 
         maxBytesLocalHeap="512M" 
         eternal="false"
         timeToIdleSeconds="90000" 
         timeToLiveSeconds="0" 
         maxBytesLocalDisk="10G"
         diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
         memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">

        <persistence strategy="localRestartable" />

    </defaultCache>
</ehcache>
```

**Complains**:

```
net.sf.ehcache.config.InvalidConfigurationException: 
Cannot use localRestartable persistence and disk overflow in the same cache
...
net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCache(CacheManager.java:1177)

 play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin.cache$lzycompute(Cache.scala:143)

 play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin.cache(Cache.scala:142)

 play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin.onStart(Cache.scala:159)
...
```

**Question**: How can I change persistence strategy to something different than `disk overflow`? How can I configure ehcache to use the hard drive for caching?

Comment: Hey, I earned a [tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) badge for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the EhCache documentation [here](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/fast-restart.html)

> • “localRestartable” — Enables the RestartStore and copies all cache entries (on-heap and/or off-heap) to disk. This option provides fast restartability with fault tolerant cache persistence on disk. This option is available for **BigMemory Go only**.

The BigMemory Go is a paid product from Terracotta which is not open source. This maybe why you are getting the error.